# How to check the output of diff command in shell script?

Tags: shell

I have to compare a file with 3 different golden files using `diff`.
I need to exit the script with `exit 0` if test file is the same as any of the three golden files.

I tried the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
one=`diff -q NEW_GOLDEN_OUTPUT_ASYNC_1 /tmp/tmp_last_lines.log`
two=`diff -q NEW_GOLDEN_OUTPUT_ASYNC_2 /tmp/tmp_last_lines.log`
three=`diff -q NEW_GOLDEN_OUTPUT_ASYNC_3 /tmp/tmp_last_lines.log`

if [[ $one || $two || $three ]]; then
  exit 0
else
  exit 1
fi
```

But it returns `exit 0` in all cases. I'm using /bin/ksh shell. Any suggestions?

Comment: To check if two files are identical use 

`if cmp -s "$source_file" "$dest_file"; then
    : # files are the same
else
    : # files are different
fi`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks at the output of `diff` but you should look at the exit code. Try this instead:

```
#!/bin/sh
diff -q NEW_GOLDEN_OUTPUT_ASYNC_1 /tmp/tmp_last_lines.log && \
diff -q NEW_GOLDEN_OUTPUT_ASYNC_2 /tmp/tmp_last_lines.log && \
diff -q NEW_GOLDEN_OUTPUT_ASYNC_3 /tmp/tmp_last_lines.log
```

`&&` will only execute the next command if the previous one succeeded.

Alternatively, use `set -e` (Exit immediately if a command exits with a non-zero status.):

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
diff -q NEW_GOLDEN_OUTPUT_ASYNC_1 /tmp/tmp_last_lines.log
diff -q NEW_GOLDEN_OUTPUT_ASYNC_2 /tmp/tmp_last_lines.log
diff -q NEW_GOLDEN_OUTPUT_ASYNC_3 /tmp/tmp_last_lines.log
```